# Isotope filter link on each element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I am relatively new to this game and wanted to see if anyone could help me out?

I am trying to make a link on an element that behaves like one of my filters in the menu at the top, .graphic in this case!

Here is my menu:

```
<section id="options" >
<ul  id="nav" class="drop option-set clearfix" data-option-key="filter">
<li id="filters"><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".home" class="selected">home</a></li>
<li id="filters"><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".product">industrial design</a></li>
<li id="filters"><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".graphic">website design</a></li>
<li id="filters"><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".hosting">website hosting</a></li>
<li id="filters"><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".ip">zelo ip</a></li>
<li id="filters"><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".research">research</a></li>
<li id="filters"><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".contact">contact us</a></li>
</ul>
</section>
```

Here is the element:

```
<div class="element home width4 height2" style="background-size: 100% Auto; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0px 0px;background-image:url('images/home/004.jpg');">
<p class="weight"><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".graphic">more...</a></p></div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Demo can be seen here: http://zelo.co.uk/dynamic

Comment: Can't access the link, `403 Forbidden`

Answer (score 0):

The top menu links work properly as Isotope filters because the links are contained in a `<ul>` with the class `option-set` which itself is contained in a section with the id `options`;

```
<section id="options" >
                <ul  id="nav" class="drop option-set clearfix" data-option-key="filter">
                  <li id="filters"><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".home" class="selected">home</a></li>
                  <li id="filters"><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".product">industrial design</a></li>
.....
```

(Note that you shouldn't have the same id applied to each list item, ids should be unique).

The relevant section of your JS which is responsible for applying Isotope is below - to get this working you need to either alter your markup so that all links can be handled by the same JS function, or create a new function which targets specifically the links in the main container of the page (maybe by applying a specific class to each of them).

```
  var $optionSets = $('#options .option-set'),
      $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

  $optionLinks.click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    // don't proceed if already selected
    if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
      return false;
    }
    var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');
    $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $this.addClass('selected');

    // make option object dynamically, i.e. { filter: '.my-filter-class' }
    var options = {},
        key = $optionSet.attr('data-option-key'),
        value = $this.attr('data-option-value');
    // parse 'false' as false boolean
    value = value === 'false' ? false : value;
    options[ key ] = value;
    if ( key === 'layoutMode' && typeof changeLayoutMode === 'function' ) {
      // changes in layout modes need extra logic
      changeLayoutMode( $this, options )
    } else {
      // otherwise, apply new options
      $container.isotope( options );
    }

    return false;
  });
```